# FPS controller capsule snaps back to zero when rotating

Tags: unity, c#, rotation, first-person-shooter

I'm trying to make a simple FPS controller, but when I try to rotate my Player Capsule it just snaps back to zero

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraLook : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] Transform PlayerCapsule;
    [SerializeField]private float _mouseXsensitivity, _mouseYsensitivity;
    private float _cameraVerticalLook;
    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }
    void Update()
    {
        float xInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse X") * _mouseXsensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
        float yInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse Y") * _mouseYsensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
        _cameraVerticalLook -= yInput;
        _cameraVerticalLook = Mathf.Clamp(_cameraVerticalLook, -80, 80);

        transform.localEulerAngles = Vector3.right * _cameraVerticalLook;

        PlayerCapsule.Rotate(Vector3.up * xInput);
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what is the "it" that snaps back to zero? I see you're rotating two different objects — do you mean rotation of one or the other snaps to zero, or both? Also, don't double-dip on Time.deltaTime in mouse deltas. Mouse movement is already one frame's displacement, not a velocity that needs to be integrated over a timestep.

Comment: @DMGregory, "Mouse movement is already one frame's displacement, not a velocity that needs to be integrated over a timestep" .Game speed may be affected by a variable frame rate.  This code is correct and preferred when the the frame-rate can fluctuate, Your assumption is a fixed time step and you are wrong in that assumption.

Comment: No, I'm not assuming a fixed time step. The Mouse X and Mouse Y axes in Unity do not store mouse movement speed in pixels/second, but mouse displacement since the last frame, in pixels. If the mouse is moving at a constant speed, then on short frames the value will be smaller and on long frames the value will be larger — it already incorporates the frame duration. Multiplying by delta time gets you a value in "pixel seconds" which doesn't make sense for the dimensional analysis, another way to check the math. So this code does not correct for variable framerate, it *adds* inconsistency.

Comment: But don't take my word for it, [read the documentarion](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetAxis.html): "This is frame-rate independent; you do not need to be concerned about varying frame-rates when using this value." It's true there are many situations where to adjust for a variable framerate you need to multiply by `deltaTime`, but this just is not one of them.